# Compile javascript with dependencies using Babel

Tags: javascript, node.js, dependencies, ecmascript-6, babeljs

How do I compile ES6 JS code with all required dependencies using `babel-cli` module? For example.

I have the next project structure:

```
/lib
 /packageA
   /node_modules
   - package.json
   - index.js
 /packageB
   /node_modules
   - package.json
   - index.js
/app
- index.js
- package.json
```

I import packages `packageA` and `packageB` in `/app/index.js`, all the components are written using ES6 syntax, except from the packages installed with `npm` in `node_modules`.

I would like to compile `/app/index.js` with all the dependencies, but cannot figure out a simple way without to explicitly provide paths of `packageA` and `packageB`.

I have found this module https://github.com/mairatma/babel-deps, but is there other tools / approaches / native babel soultions?

Comment: Are you trying to add all files into one, or just compile it with babel to see if your project compiles?

Comment: doesn't really matter, i want to get a compiled js code

Comment: what was the solution?

Comment: @Nth.gol don't quite remember, but now I'd say it's not babel's responsibility to bundle the code, so some sort of bundler should be used instead (e.g. webpack or rollup)

Answer (score 6):

If you compile several files with `babel` it will concat the files. If what you want is to get a compiled file in `app/index.js` that includes the dependencies I would recommend using something like [rollup](http://rollupjs.org/).

If you decide to go with rollup, a `rollup.config.js` like this will do what I think you want:

```
import nodeResolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';

export default {
  entry: 'index.js',
  dest: 'app/app.js',
  plugins: [
    babel(),
    nodeResolve(), 
    commonjs()]
};
```

And then just run `rollup -c`

Comment: thanks! feels like the right direction, however bumped into compilation problem with 3rd party module, trying to fix it